# how to properly delete a pointer to array

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm confused about arrays and pointers. Could someone tell me how I can properly delete a pointer. Like for example,

```
int *foo;
foo = new int[10];

delete foo;
```

or

```
delete [] foo;
```

Thanks.

Comment: if all the answers are correct how can i accept it all, i dont like choosing only one, since all them are nice to answer my question?

Comment: You cannot accept all.  You can up-vote all if you found all of them helpful, but you should accept one.  Criteria for acceptance are suggested in the FAQ, but might include correctness, usefulness, completeness, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The requirement to match `new[]` with `delete[]` is technically correct.

Much better, however (at least in my opinion), would be to forget that you ever even heard of `new[]`, and never use it again. I'm pretty sure it's been (at least) 10 years since the last time I used `new[]`, and if I'd understood the situation very well, I'd have stopped even sooner than that. Pretty nearly any time you'd even consider using `new[]`, an `std::vector` (or possibly `std::deque`) will be a better choice.

If you're trying to create something roughly equivalent to a `vector` or `deque` yourself, you don't normally want to use `new[]` for that either. They way they (at least normally, though it's possible to change this via a custom `Allocator` class) is to allocate "raw" storage with `operator new` (which is pretty much like `malloc`--you just give it a size, and it gives you that many bytes of storage). Then you use the placement `new` operator to create objects in that space, and explicitly invoke the object's destructor to destroy objects in that space.

To give one example, this is what allows `std::vector` to support `reserve`, which allows you to allocate extra space, which won't be turned into objects until you call something like `push_back` or `emplace_back` to create an actual object in the space you allocated.

When you use `new[]`, it has to create objects of the specified type filling all the space you allocate. You can't create something like `push_back` that adds a new object to the collection, because the collection is always already "full". All you can do is allocate a new collection that's larger than the old one (so every addition to the collection is O(N) instead of  the amortized O(1) supported by `std::vector`--a huge loss of efficiency).

Comment: What if you were trying to build a string class, or something useful like that? Blanket bans on new are bad.

Comment: The blanket ban would be on new[], not on new. A collection class (including a string) should invoke ::new(size_t); directly. When you use new[], it creates an array of objects -- i.e. all those positions are allocated AND constructed. 

A collection should NOT create objects in the empty space (merely pointless for a string, positively harmful if the objects are expensive to construct). Instead, it should allocate uninitialized storage, and then use placement new to create objects in that storage.

Answer (score 10):

It's:

```
delete[] foo;
```

**Edit: Modern compilers really need you to use the correct `delete` operator, or they may leak memory or fail to run the proper destructors.**

(I earlier stated that it didn't make a difference in practice. About 10 years ago, I tried many different compilers and failed to find one that actually leaked memory if you mistakenly omitted the `[]`. However the howls of the mob - see below - have forced me to re-try my experimentation, and it seems that modern compilers/libc++s really do care.)

Comment: Even if compilers do the right thing with `delete`, I think using `delete []` is still better practice -- both for cases where you run into compilers that do not do the right thing, but also as a declaration of intent.

Comment: Compilers might not leak memory, but they likely won't call destructors without the `[]`...

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a compiler which allows you to use delete when delete[] is expected. They always produce code that blows up when I do it.

Comment: @alex: It __WILL__ leak memory. But because you used the wrong delete you have messed up the internal memory structure used by the memory management routines. Thus it is quite possible that the it will not be reported by any tools that try and monitor memory leaks.

Comment: They might not leak memory when you use types with trivial dtors. For UDT's with non-trivial dtors, however, this is quite different, because `delete` won't call all the dtors.

Comment: bdonlan, jalf, Martin: thanks for pointing out my mistake - corrected now. Clearly C++ compilers/runtimes are more sophisticated than they were when I tried this experiment, back in the last century!

Comment: At least Visual C++ 8.0 will be able to detect mismatches between array/non-array new and delete (when called with the /analyze switch). And the generated programs will leak if the wrong delete has been used (for classes with destructors).

Answer (score 5):

If you allocate an array of objects using the `new []` operator then you must use the `delete []` operator and therefore the non-array `new` can only be used with the non-array `delete`.

```
int *a = new int[10];
int *b = new int;

delete [] a;
delete b;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do `new <type>[]` you must do `delete []`. It's a simple enough rule, and worth remembering.

Answer (score 2):

You walked in the front door and left it open. Then you walked through to the back door and tried to close it but you smashed it because it was already closed.

```
foo = new int [10];  // so when you open the front door
delete [] foo;       // please remember to close the front door.

foo = new int;       // and when you open the back door
delete foo;          // please remember to close the back door.
```

Don't mix them up!

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you `new`ed an array you use `delete[]`. Sometimes you new'ed an array using `new` - then you still have to use `delete[]` - no way out. So it's not exactly a rule "use delete[] when you new[]'ed" but rather "use delete[] when deleting an array".

```
typedef int array[5];

int *a = new array;
delete[] a; // still delete[] !
```